# understand java error + in WIN XP

Tags: java

I tries to exe some java application from my PC (WIN XP)
during execution I get some error as described below down
I don’t expect to get absolute answer , but because I don’t know java maybe someone will help 
about the following problem and tell me what the problem mean?
and maybe its because wrong PC configuration (regional and settings?) ?

```
2010-02-26 23:34:05,260 | ERROR | com.bob.localization.ResourceManager |   Error  loading resource bundle: localized.CustomCSMAppErrors | main |  
   java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name            localized.CustomCSMAppErrors, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
at com.com.localization.ResourceManager.addResourceBundle(ResourceManager.java:286)
at com.com.localization.ResourceManager.addResourceBundle(ResourceManager.java:252)
at com.com.localization.ResourceManager.initializeForLocale(ResourceManager.java:107)
at com.com.fxframe.setup.FXFrameSetup.setupApplicationConfiguration(FXFrameSetup.java:66)
```

Comment: Looks like the application is missing files.

Comment: "com.comverse.localization.ResourceManager" seems to be proprietary. Maybe the specific language en_US isn't support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing bundle files of your application. Resource bundle is used for multilanguage support in java apps.
I think it isn't a configuration problem. If you have the source code you can try using another ResourceBundle or fixing the path(if you have that bundle but the path is wrong), otherwise I think you can't do anything.

Comment: please advice what I need to do , I need to fix something in my PC conf?

Comment: @david: what's your language?

Comment: I configure in the regional and language to work with English (US)

Comment: maybe as you sais its a PATH problem (ENV)?

Comment: @david: maybe it's a path problem inside your java app (Not ENV). You are configuring language where? Which application are you trying to use? Have you got the source code?